# Ion Auth User and Admin Issue - CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I'm using Ion Auth for my website authentication, and it's a wonderful tool with one slight issue. Whenever a user is created, they are automatically created as an administrator and not a member or general user even though this is specified within my ion_auth config file. Has anyone else come across this issue, or know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In application/config/ion_auth.php

```
$config['default_group'] = 'members';
```

'members' must be inserted in the 'groups' table defined by:

```
$config['tables']['groups'] = 'groups';
```

If this not works the problem is in another part...

Comment: This is correct in my config and db table. I ran the query from Ion Auth's included SQL file, and checked to make sure it was correct. No dice.

Comment: Found out what the issue was. Ben Edmunds hasn't loaded the current version of ion_auth on his website benedmunds.com/ion_auth which caused the issue. Thanks for your help!